# How to create a variable path in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using this php to pull in snippets of content, I'm trying to build a static styleguide of sorts.

The PHP below works, but I might have 10 or 15 snippets of content per page. It'd be handy if I could store the bulk of the path in a variable:

```
 <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/perch/addons/feathers/theme/styleguide/includes/imgs/img-323x182.php"); ?>
```

How would I store the first part of this path in a variable?

```
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/perch/addons/feathers/theme/styleguide/
```

So each snippet of content would look something like this:

```
 <?php $path includes/imgs/img-323x182.php"); ?>
```

Comment: $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/perch/addons/feathers/theme/styleguide/ and then include($path.includes/imgs/img-323x182.php")

Comment: Database, session, cookies?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick!

Answer (score 4):

Ignore the fact that it's a path: It's really just a string.

```
$foo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/perch/etc....";

include("{$foo}/whatever");
```

It doesn't become a path until you use it in a filesystem context.